# Change Contact Form 7 default time format

Tags: wordpress, timestamp, contact-form-7

I need to change the time format for contact form 7's [_time] upon form submission. I'm using it as a timestamp to show when a form is submitted, but I may get 30 per minute.

The default is:
{hour} : {minute} {am/pm}

I need seconds as well: hour:minute:second

Answer (score 0):

Please check the proper time set:

```
$date->setTime(14, 55);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settime.php